# "git remote : fatal: the empty string is not a valid path" error from git push

Tags: git, github, uploading

I'm using Git, and am trying to push my changes:

```
git push origin master
```

It seems to start uploading, but then I get this error:

```
remote : fatal: the empty string is not a valid path
```

I don't understand what it's saying. How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you add and commit files before you tried too push? also make sure you are in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try and check what your remote origin is referring to:

```
git remote -v
```

If it doesn't reference a proper path/url for your remote repo, you can change it with:

```
git remote set-url origin /url/to/remote/repo
```

You can see that error message introduced in [git 1.8.0 (commit 3efe5d1)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3efe5d1d32fde899b23ebbb1fde499a0897e1c4e), with the thread [discussing the issue there](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/PATCH-v2-0-8-Fix-some-bugs-in-abspath-c-td7566454.html).

If it starts uploading, that should mean the git remote url is enough to contact the git server, but the path or the remote repo on that server is somehow incorrect.